# javascript click event handler fires without clicking

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, click

Why does this function get fired without having clicked on the specified button?
I had a look at a few similar problems but none deal with this code structure (might be obvious reason for this im missing...).

```
document.getElementById("main_btn").addEventListener("click", hideId("main");

function hideId(data) {
    document.getElementById(data).style.display = "none";
    console.log("hidden element #"+data);
}
```

Comment: Use an html onClick tag, should I post an answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are directly calling it.

```
document.getElementById("main_btn").addEventListener("click", hideId("main");
```

You should do that in a callback.

```
document.getElementById("main_btn").addEventListener("click", function (){
    hideId("main");
});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! It all makes sense now, I saw this solution come by a few times but I didn't understand why you had to call the function within another function. But I guess you're telling the event handler to execute the function after clicking instead of just putting it there to execute by itself.

Answer (score 3):

This code executes your function `hideId("main")` you should pass just the callback's name:

```
document.getElementById("main_btn").addEventListener("click", hideId);

function hideId(event) {
    var id = event.target.srcElement.id; // get the id of the clicked element
    document.getElementById(data).style.display = "none";
    console.log("hidden element #"+data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("main_btn").addEventListener("click", hideId.bind(null, "main");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.