# function running without waiting for event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with very basic js function. I've looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042901/javascript-click-event-handler-fires-without-clicking) topic on SO which is very similar but it didn't help me.

So I want to run a function after the div is clicked. My first attempt would cause the function to run without clicking it:

### 1st attempt

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('button').addEventListener("click", slide());

function slide(){
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
  x.innerHTML = "test123";
}
```

```css
.button{
  height:60px;
  background-color:darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="button"></div>
```

Then after adjusting my code to what I read in the answer provided in the topic I linked above I created something like this:

### 2nd attempt

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('button').addEventListener("click", function(){
 slide();
});

function slide(){
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
  x.innerHTML = "test123";
}
```

```css
.button{
  height:60px;
  background-color:darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="button"></div>
```

But then nothing happens at all after clicking the `div`. I also tried to do it like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button').addEventListener("click", slide);
```

But then also nothing happens. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you have an id it is preferable to use it. getElementsByClassName returns a collection, so you would have to index it `[0]` to add a listener to the first element of the collection.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/settimeout-calls-function-immediately-instead-of-after-delay) is why the first one didn't work, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) is why the second one didn't work. Re the second: Always be sure to check your web console for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to issues in your code:

1. You should not execute the function in `addEventListener`.
2. `getElementsByClassName` returns collection. So you have to use proper index when use `getElementsByClassName`.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].addEventListener("click", slide);

function slide(){
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
  x.innerHTML = "test123";
}
```

```css
.button{
  height:60px;
  background-color:darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="button"></div>
```

Comment: Don't answer obvious, common duplicates. Instead, vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder more than that, the answer doesn't explain what `getElementsByClassName` returns.

Comment: @Ele: Indeed. :-) It does at least hint at it with the "index" thing, but...

Comment: @ Mamun - My first comment above should have started with "Please". Sorry about that.