# innerHTML and addEventListener doesn't work on html and javascript site

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner for javascript and HTML. and now working on my assignment from an online course.
I'm currently making 3 minutes timer using HTML, CSS, and javascript.
I borrowed javascript code form online and changing some codes to understand what's written in javascript.
I have two questions...

one is when I put **addEventListener('click', startTimer(), false);** it just doesn't seem to work properly, and more like it's already triggering function in the javascript file. so I want to know why it's happening.

second is that innerHTML is not working. I tried to put **document.getElementsByClassName('start').innerHTML = "START";** in javascript file, but I don't see 'START' on the web page. I don't actually need to insert innerHTML for START button but I tried to change other HTML part using innerHTML it's not working so I wonder why that's happening.

does somebody know how to make them work?

thank you!

```js
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "03" + ":" + "00";
    document.getElementsByClassName('start').innerHTML = "START";
    var start = document.getElementsByClassName('start');
    start.addEventListener('click', startTimer(), false);
    var stop = document.getElementsByClassName('stop');
    stop.removeEventListener('click', startTimer(), false);
    var reset = document.getElementsByClassName('reset');

    function startTimer() {
      var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
      var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
      var m = timeArray[0];
      var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
      if(s==59){m=m-1}
      //if(m<0){alert('timer completed')}
      
      document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
        m + ":" + s;
      console.log(m)
      setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
    }

    function checkSecond(sec) {
      if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {sec = "0" + sec}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
      if (sec < 0) {sec = "59"};
      return sec;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html class="no-js" lang="ja">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title id="countdown-timer">3 Minutes Timer</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="timer-title">
                <p>3 Minutes Timer</p>
            </div>
            <div class="timer-box">
                <div class="timer-outer-display">
                    <div class="timer-display">
                        <div>
                            <p id="timer" ></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button class="start"></button>
                    <button class="stop">STOP</button>
                    <button class="reset">RESET</button>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: also see this for `addEventListener` issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715655/why-is-listner-function-running-without-the-click-event/56715680#56715680

Comment: In short, `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return one element, it returns an array-like collection of elements (as there can be multiple elements with the one class). You can use `.querySelector('.start')` to get one element with the class.  `addEventListener` expects a function to be passed to it. You're firstly calling `startTimer()` and then using the return value of `startTimer()` as the function. Instead just use `.addEventLister('click', startTimer, false)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: Thank you.. I updated, following Nick's advises and now the timer seems work fine. though I found more things to fix now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to indicate the element number of the collection...

```
var start = document.getElementsByClassName('start')[0];
```

NB: Square brackets.

Comment: Thank you 4723924. I understood how to use getElementsByClassName method. I updated on my web and working good. Thank you for helping me out.